My network to classify dialects is not working
I have written the following code to classify dialects based on the timit dataset using .wav files. For some reason my model is not learning and classifies everything into the same class. Is it necessary to convert to spectrogram? If so how can this be done? Can some one please guide me in the right direction as to why this is happening? Thanks in advance.


import os
import torchaudio
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import random
import deeplake
import librosa
import numpy as np
import logging

not_all_files = True
# Configure the logger
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class VoiceClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VoiceClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 20, kernel_size=(1, 3), padding=(0, 1))
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(20, 64, kernel_size=(1, 3), padding=(0, 1))
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 50000, 64)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 2)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=-1)

    def forward(self, x):
        logger.info(f"x1.shape: {x.shape}")
        x = self.relu(self.conv1(x))
        logger.info(f"x2.shape: {x.shape}")
        x = self.relu(self.conv2(x))
        logger.info(f"x3.shape: {x.shape}")
        batch_size = x.shape[0]
        x = x.view(batch_size, -1)
        logger.info(f"x4.shape: {x.shape}")
        x = self.relu(self.fc1(x))
        logger.info(f"x5.shape: {x.shape}")
        x = self.fc2(x)
        logger.info(f"x6.shape: {x.shape}")
        x = self.softmax(x)
        logger.info(f"x7.shape: {x.shape}")
        return x


# Define the custom dataset
class TIMITDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root_dir, dialects, transform=None):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.dialects = dialects
        self.transform = transform
        self.samples = []
        self.max_length = 50000

        # Randomly select two dialects
        selected_dialects = random.sample(dialects, 2)

        # Load the audio files and their labels
        for dialect, label in zip(selected_dialects, [0, 1]):
            dialect_dir = os.path.join(root_dir, dialect)
            for filename in os.listdir(dialect_dir):
                if not_all_files:
                    if filename.endswith(".WAV"):
                        file_path = os.path.join(dialect_dir, filename)
                        self.samples.append((file_path, label))
                else:
                    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dialect_dir, filename)):
                        sub_file_path = os.path.join(dialect_dir, filename)
                        for file in os.listdir(sub_file_path):
                            if file.endswith(".WAV"):
                                f_path = os.path.join(sub_file_path, file)
                                self.samples.append((f_path, label))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.samples)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        file_path, label = self.samples[idx]
        waveform, sample_rate = librosa.load(file_path, sr=None)
        # Pad or truncate the waveform to a fixed length
        if self.max_length is not None:
            waveform = self.pad_or_truncate(waveform, self.max_length)

        waveform = torch.from_numpy(waveform).unsqueeze(0)
        if self.transform:
            waveform = self.transform(waveform)
        return waveform, label

    def pad_or_truncate(self, waveform, max_length):
        length = waveform.shape[-1]
        if length > max_length:
            waveform = waveform[:max_length]
        else:
            padding = max_length - length
            offset = padding // 2
            waveform = np.pad(waveform, (offset, padding - offset), mode="constant")
        return waveform


# Path to the directory where you extracted the TIMIT dataset
dataset_path = "/home/paul/Documents/Projects/voice_model/data"

# List of available dialects in the TIMIT Corpus
dialects = ["dr5", "dr6"]

# Create the dataset and data loaders
train_dataset = TIMITDataset(os.path.join(dataset_path, "TRAIN"), dialects)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True)

test_dataset = TIMITDataset(os.path.join(dataset_path, "TEST"), dialects)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, shuffle=True)

# Initialize the model, loss function, and optimizer
model = VoiceClassifier()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Training loop
num_epochs = 10
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    running_loss = 0.0
    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        inputs = inputs.unsqueeze(1)  # Add channel dimension
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        logger.info(f"len of dataset: {train_dataset.__len__()}")
        logger.info(f"input shape: {inputs.shape}")
        outputs = model(inputs)
        logger.info(f"output shape: {outputs.shape}")
        logger.info(f"output: {outputs}\n")

        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}, Loss: {running_loss / len(train_loader)}")

# Evaluation
model.eval()
correct = 0
total = 0
with torch.no_grad():
    for inputs, labels in test_loader:
        inputs = inputs.unsqueeze(1)
        outputs = model(inputs)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

print(f"Accuracy: {100 * correct / total}%")

```

